Understanding 一人分は自腹で来た
In Quintessential Quintuplets chapter 61, Uesugi won a raffle and it earned him and his family a vacation. The below is a conversation between family members

I am not sure what 一人分は自腹で来たかいがあるってもんだ means, especially 一人分は自腹で来た. I think it is saying "there's merit in coming here with by paying one person's worth of tickets"? Maybe there is a limit in how many people can go to the vacation and one of the family members has to pay for a ticket using his own money?

Yes. Did you notice the phrase "温泉ペアチケット" several pages earlier? The prize was two tickets for an onsen, which is the standard offering for this type of 福引き. So, if three people are traveling, someone needs to pay for the trip for the third person out of pocket.

一人分は自腹で来たかいがあるってもんだ
It's worth the visit even if we have to cover one person's expenses.


Thanks, I can't believe that I overlooked this piece of text. But the font was too small so it is no wonder that I missed it.
